# STM8: local declared pointer on global variable

Tags: c, pointers

on my STM8 Disco Board with Cosmic Compiler I tried follwoing code and expected 'ptr_a' and 'ptr_aLocal' to be the same:

```
int a, b, *ptr_a, *ptr_b;

void main()
    {
    int *ptr_aLocal;
    a = 4;
    b = 5;
    ptr_a = &a;
    ptr_b = &b;
    ptr_aLocal = &a;
    }
```

However, 'ptr_a' has the correct address for variable 'a' whereas 'ptr_aLocal' contains a wrong adress.

When compileing the same code with gcc 'ptr_a' and 'ptr_aLocal' are as expected the same.

Whats the problem here when declaring the pointer local in main?

Thank you for your help.
Rafael

Edit:

Now I'm realy confused:
When adding the line 'ptr_b = ptr_aLocal;' at the end of the code, ptr_b shows the correct adress of Variable 'a' (0x106), although 'ptr_aLocal' still contains the wrong adress of variable a (0x108)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DkQb.png)

Comment: How are you viewing the values? Have you made sure the last line has executed before checking the value?

Comment: @Rafael After this statement ptr_aLocal = &a; place this statement printf( "%d\n", ptr_a == ptr_aLocal ); and see whether 1 is outputted.

Comment: @Tordek: I'm viewing the values with ST Visual Develops Debugger. When running the gcc exe i used printf to output the values. Yes ptr_aLocal = &a; has been executed.

Comment: @Vlad: Where is printf supposed to output, when the code runs on the STM8?

Comment: Have you disabled all optimizations? The line might not do anything since it's assigning a local variable and exiting immediately.

Comment: I set optimization to Disable for Debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various older versions of misc embedded compilers tended to optimize code somewhat even when optimizations were supposedly disabled. Particularly Cosmic and Codewarrior had such quirks in older versions. Since the local variable isn't used, it is optimized away.

You can see this for yourself by viewing the generated assembler - any half-decent debugger will support assembly step debugging. If there is no stack push or index register store instruction there, then it was optimized away.

You can force the variable to get used with `volatile int *ptr_aLocal`.

---

Unrelated to your question, you should use `uint8_t` as far as possible nad not `int`, when programming 8 bit microcontrollers.

Comment: @Rafael So check the disassembly in your debugger. Is the instruction generated or not?

Comment: In the disassembly the instruction `ptr_aLocal = &a;` is not generated. But when adding the line `ptr_b = ptr_aLocal;`  at the end of the code, ptr_b shows the correct adress of Variable 'a' (0x106), although 'ptr_aLocal' still contains the wrong adress of variable a (0x108)

Comment: @Rafael Post the disassembled function. It might be that the local variable is stored in an index register or such. Or it's just yet another classic stack overflow bug. Check SP.

Comment: I checkt the Disassembly and the SP more clolsly. It seems that the line `ptr_aLocal = &a;` is not generated and the line `ptr_b = ptr_aLocal,` is executed using the SP. But why is `ptr_aLocal` optimized away when the setting for optimization is "Disable for Debug"?

Comment: @Rafael Because, as mentioned, various older embedded compilers tend to have shaky and questionable optimizer settings... you'll have to ask the vendor why.